# implement single sign on using adfs for tableau and redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, adfs, tableau-api

I have a tableau server which is connected to aws redshift cluster.At present we have to type the credentials for tableau and redshift separately every time.Is there any way of implementing single sign on using microsoft adfs ? I am able to implement single sign on for tableau but how can i provide the database credential.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on the Tableau side (sorry) but here is a blog post that walks you through setting up ADFS federation with AWS IAM to allow single sign on access to Amazon Redshift. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/federate-database-user-authentication-easily-with-iam-and-amazon-redshift/

Presumably Tableau has an option somewhere to simply pass through the user name to Redshift/IAM.